# Sharepoint Design schema JSON for LayoutWebpartsContent

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I am Searching for JSON format and documentation of creating a page with web parts in it using Sharepoint Design scripts JSON.

After googling, I got the Schema for creating the page but for adding WebParts there is no schema details about JSON string need to be passed.

Can anyone point me to the documentation about `LayoutWebpartsContent` property schema or example?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/design/layout-patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create Site pages using SharePoint Site designs at the moment.

It is not supported. So, adding a webpart to the page also wont work.

This capability has not been enabled by Microsoft. It might be supported in the future, but at the moment it wont work with the `createPage` verb.

Reference - [How to create a page using site scripts?](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3038#issuecomment-456079910)